# Backbone .render().$el trouble

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Im having trouble rendering a view in Backbone, and I can't figure out where my snag is.  My log error reads  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$el' of undefined` and the collection render that produces the error is as follows:

```
 render: function(){

                this.$el = $('#list_entries');

                console.log(this.$el);

                var self = this;

                self.$el.html('');

                _.each(this.model.toArray(), function(list, i){
                    self.$el.append(new ListView({model: list}).render().$el);

                });

                return this;
            }
```

This is the single entry view that the collection `render` calls

```
 var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({

                model: new List(),
                tagName: 'div',
                className: 'singleList',

                initialize: function(){

                    this.template = _.template($('#list_template').html());
                },

                render: function(){

                    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                }
        });
```

The odd thing is that I am using the exact same method to render another view and dont have this issue.

Comment: Use `self.$el.append` instead inside `_.each` callback.

Comment: I appologize...I had self.$el.append before I started debugging. The console error now reads:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$el' of undefined

Comment: Never do `this.$el = $('#list_entries')`, always use [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) if you need such shenanigans and you almost never need such things anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your `render` is missing `return this;`

```
render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
```

Also,

You can pass in this into `_.each`

```
_.each(this.model.toArray(), function(list, i){
    this.$el.append(new ListView({model: list}).render().$el);
}, this);
```

Then you won't need `var self = this;` at all

Answer (score 0):

You should use `self` in the `_.each` callback to have the correct scope.

```
_.each(this.model.toArray(), function(list, i){
    self.$el.append(new ListView({model: list}).render().$el);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the context of this in the `_.each` function call back is not the view that you think it is. Try using `self.$el.append` instead.

Comment: I appologize...I had `self.$el.append` before I started debugging.  The console error now reads:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$el' of undefined`

Comment: i realized that i didnt end my single entry view with `return this` and this prevented my _.each function from chaining

Comment: I think @Vic has the right answer below that addresses both the context and the chaining issues. You should accept that answer.